# My reputation in my profile doesn't match my reputation shown in a user card on an answer

Tags: bug, android-app

When I go to the app and in my profile I see my previous reputation not the current. But when I click on a question I answered I can see there my current reputation points. Any explanation or is it a bug?[image: from profile]
[image: from answered]

Comment: Can you elaborate? Which app are you using - Android or iOS? Are you talking about your reputation points or a score on a question or answer?

Comment: Reputation points and I'm using android. It's reputation in both case

Comment: Your rep is underconstruction

Comment: @Won't i can update that it's showing the correct reputation today. I don't know that why it didn't updated that time on both places. Thanks

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Won't Hahaha that was awesome. so should i remove this question or you want to post an solution?

Comment: Somebody will come along and close as dupe of the canonical "why is my reputation over here not the same as over there" question.  I don't know which canonical that is :/